# Comparing five columns of two different files and printing the differences of only two columns using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk, compare

so I have the first file as shown below:

first.txt:

```
id|name|place|cost|member|
1|max|USA|55|yes|
2|Jhon|France|99|No|
3|Mary|Canada|777|yes|
4|Berry|USA|888|yes|
5|Stella|Mexico|100|yes|
```

and the file second.txt:

```
id|name|place|cost|member|
1|max|USA|55|No|
2|Jhon|France|99|No|
3|Mary|Canada|770|yes|
4|Berry|USA|888|yes|
5|Stella|Mexico|101|No|
```

So here I want to compare these two files according to the three first columns that should be the same and print the differences if they exist in the 4th and 5th column

In this example, The output I want is:

For the id: 1 and name: max and country: USA the Member is changed from Yes to No

For the id: 3 and name: Mary and country: Canada the cost is changed from 777 to 770

For the id: 5 and name: Stella and country: Mexico the cost is change from 100 to 101 and the Member is changed from Yes to No

Knowing that my files may contain thousands of lines and don't have the same size.

I tried the awk command but couldn't combine difference and then similarity and also the output is missing lines, and also the print didn't know where to put:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR++FNR{C[$1,$2,$3]++;C[$4,$5]++; next} C[$1,$2,$3] > 0 && C[$4,$5] == 0'
```

Comment: Without any deeper examination, `NR++FNR` should be `NR==FNR`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should get you started

```
$ awk -F'|'   '{k=$1 FS $2 FS $3} 
     NR==1     {split($0,h)}
     NR==FNR   {f4[k]=$4; f5[k]=$5; next} 
     f4[k]!=$4 {print k, h[4] " changed from " f4[k] " to " $4}' file1 file2

3|Mary|Canada cost changed from 777 to 770
5|Stella|Mexico cost changed from 100 to 101
```

do the same for field 5 and also you can print the key in your verbose format as well.  Column names are kept in the `h[]` array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt and clear answer! i was thinking if there is a way to print this output only in case the first 3 columns exist in both files and not be printed in the case where id, name, and place are unique to only one file, Thank you!

Comment: you can add the check `!(k in f4){next}` before the value match statements to skip unmatched keys.